# Using django-nose and unittest-xml-reporting together - unit testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage, django-nose

We have a django project that using [unittest-xml-reporting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-xml-reporting) to provide bamboo with xml files about the test results. We would like to integrate [django-nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) to test for code coverage. But since django tests require a single `TEST_RUNNER` class, I don't see how to use in parallel both functionalities (which actually don't overlap):

for unittest-xml-reporting

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner'
```

for django-nose

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

I've tried to get into the code, but it seems messy to write some kind of hack to join the classes together. What other options are left?

Answer (score 6):

Why not using just **django-nose** to generate xjunit XML? Just add these lines:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--verbosity=2',  # verbose output
    '--with-xunit',  # enable XUnit plugin
    '--xunit-file=xunittest.xml',  # the XUnit report file
]
```

This way you don't have to work with subclassing both Runners, which is the only way to do: creating a custom Runner and merging both what can be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Actually I ended up using py.test which provides junitxml and code coverage. Thank you very much for you answer.

Comment: django-nose also integrates coverage, but yes py.test is an alternative